# Como funciona o arquivo PNG

Tags: imagem

Eu estava olhando essa imagem [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] e ela tem `8,21 KBs(8210 Bytes)`, seu tamanho é `100x100px`, totalizando `10.000 pixeis`.
Então a cada `(8210 / 10000) 0.821 Byte` ele consegue salvar posição e cor.

Como isso é feito ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não existe só PNG de 256 cores, existem imagens PNG 24bits e 32bits e não são só compostas de pixels, mas são compostas de varias camadas (**filtros**), logo seu calculo não é correto, as cores também pode representar pesos diferentes.

Note que uma imagem, mesmo 256 cores sendo mais larga que uma outra imagem no entanto mais baixa ao mesmo tempo pode pesar menos, mesmo que o "ratio" da imagem se mantenha relativamente.

Dependendo da escala de cores, uma imagem idêntica a outra (ambas sendo PNG) pode pesar muito mais, tanto que existem técnicas, softwares e serviços que são feitos para otimizar ao máximo arquivos png sem perder a qualidade visual da imagem, exemplos:

- https://pngquant.org
- http://optipng.sourceforge.net/pngtech/optipng.html
- https://tinypng.com (web)
- https://pngmini.com/lossypng.html (Mac OSX)

Um artigo que explica sobre o funcionamento dos filtros e compressão:

- https://medium.com/@duhroach/how-png-works-f1174e3cc7b7

Especificações:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-png.pdf
- https://www.w3.org/Graphics/PNG/